# Ubuntu 16, Snap and Dekko

Tags: 16.04, email, snap

I am just upgrading my 14.04-LTS to 15.04-LTS and have been looking at installing Dekko.

I can't seem to find out much about it. Is there a website for it's developer? I found a link to Dekko at GitLab but they wanted me to Register and waiting --- waiting --- waiting, but not sure if that's going to give me any useful information.

Is Dekko free and open source or commercial?

Comment: Did you actually mean 16.04? 15.04 isn't LTS.

Comment: Make sure to read that warning on the OMGUbuntu page : The new "Dekko is under active, ongoing development. It should not be considered stable. You will encounter bugs. Emails may get eaten."

Comment: @albertj Thanks, yes I did notice that. Claws is my main email, but has some flaky behavior at times so was looking for something better to run in parallel for a while.

Comment: @popey Yup, I meant 16.04. I am old I fumble keyboards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dekko is free/open source. The snap only works on Ubuntu 16.04 and above. Here's the main developer page:-

https://launchpad.net/dekko

There's also a telegram group (linked from the page above) where the developer and other community people hang out.

This OMG Ubuntu article details how to install it:-

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/01/install-dekko-ubuntu-email-app-snap

In short:-

```
sudo snap install --edge --devmode ubuntu-app-platform
sudo snap install --edge --devmode dekko
```

To run it:-

```
snap run dekko
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the OMG-U story that got me interested, but I like to know as much as possible about stuff before installing.